# Set limits of colormap in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am plotting three `surf` plots in a `groupplot` environment with `pgfplots`. For the third groupplot, I have enabled the `colorbar`. I would like the colorbar to represent all three plots, so equal `z` values should have equal colors. I can set `zmax` on the group plot, but this will only limit the axes in a 3D plot, the colormap appears to be applied from the minimal to the maximal value, regardless of the value of `zmin` and `zmax`. Is there a way to make the range of a colormap correspond to `zmin` and `zmax`? (Clamping will not be a problem in this case, because `zmax` is chosen such that nothing is clamped. The problem is that currently, one of my plots reaches only about half of `zmax`, but at this point the colormap is still at maximum intensity.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style = {group size = 3 by 1, horizontal sep = 1.5cm},
                  zmax = 50, view = {0}{90}]
\nextgroupplot[xlabel = $x_2$, ylabel = $x_3$]
\addplot3[surf, shader = interp] table {data-x2x3.dat};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel = $x_3$, ylabel = $x_1$]
\addplot3[surf, shader = interp] table {data-x3x1.dat};
\nextgroupplot[xlabel = $x_1$, ylabel = $x_2$, colorbar]
\addplot3[surf, shader = interp] table {data-x1x2.dat};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You can set `point meta max=..., point meta min=...`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! If you turn your comment into an answer I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Jake said in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240125/set-limits-of-colormap-in-pgfplots#comment570378_240125), the properties to set are `point meta min` and `point meta max` on the axis (or `groupplot` in this case).